# Improper type conversion in input parameter of function

Tags: c, function, input, producer-consumer

I am getting the following error for the code that I have written. 
Cannot convert `char (*)[10][256]` to `char*` for argument `1` to `int pushInBuffer(char*)`.
I can't figure out as to what type of input parameter should I introduce to `pushInBuffer()`.

```
void *consumer(void *var) {
    int i;
    //char  line[256];
    for(;;) {
        if(popFromBuffer(&buf))      
            fprintf(stderr, "Error Consuming");
        else {
            for(i = 0; i < BUFFERSIZE; i++)
                fputs(buf[i], out);
        }
    }   
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int popFromBuffer(char *item) {   // How do I give a 2_D array as input parameter and access in the function.
    sem_wait(&fullCount);          
    sem_wait(&mutex);       
    *item = buf[removePointer][256];
    buf[removePointer++][256] = -1;
    removePointer = removePointer % BUFFERSIZE;

    sem_post(&mutex);       
    sem_post(&emptyCount );    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show how you call `pushInBuffer` and the type of `pushInBuffer` argument.

Comment: @ouah  Sorry, I realized and  just edit the question.

Comment: It's still incomplete you don't show the declaration of `buf` variable.

Comment: Where is `buf` declared???

Comment: @barak : I edited again. its declared globally.

Comment: If it's a global variable then you don't need to pass it to any function!!!

Comment: Alright. Suppose I want to copy in  another variable than should I do it like  `char *item[10][256] = buf[10][256]`  ??

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: if you use buf as global you don't need to pass it from function to function.

// How do I give a 2_D array as input parameter and access in the function.

```
int popFromBuffer( char *item );
```

change to

```
int popFromBuffer( char* item[] );
```

and

```
buf[BUFFERSIZE][256]  change to char* buf[BUFFERSIZE];
```

or you could do it with structure

```
typedef struct _BUF
{
buf[BUFFERSIZE][256];
}BUF;

int popFromBuffer(BUF b);  
{
/* access buffer */
b.buf

}

int main()
{
BUF b ={0};
popFromBuffer(b);
return 0;
}
```